# how to loop over the child divs of a div and get the ids of the child divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with id test

and through the foreach loop I am creating some inner divs inside the test div. So it becomes like this.

```
<div id="test">
<div id="test-1"></div>
<div id="test-2"></div>
<div id="test-3"></div>
<div id="test-4"></div>
</div>
```

I am getting the parent div id "test" in the javascript function. Now I want to loop through the inner divs(child divs) of the test div and get the id of the each div one by one and style them through javascript.

Any Idea about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can loop through inner divs using jQuery .each() function. The following example does this and for each inner div it gets the id attribute.

```
$('#test').find('div').each(function(){
    var innerDivId = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 38):

Try this

```
var childDivs = document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('div');

for( i=0; i< childDivs.length; i++ )
{
 var childDiv = childDivs[i];
}
```

Comment: Works but needs a declaration before i. Should be `for( var i=0; i< childDivs.length; i++ )`

Answer (score 5):

Here's the solution if somebody still looks for it

```
function getDivChildren(containerId, elementsId) {
    var div = document.getElementById(containerId),
        subDiv = div.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        myArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < subDiv.length; i++) {
        var elem = subDiv[i];
        if(elem.id.indexOf(elementsId) === 0) {
            myArray.push(elem.id);
        }
    }
    return myArray;
}
console.log(getDivChildren('test', 'test-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('[id^=test-]')
```

and [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

this way for example :

```
$('[id^=test-]').each(function(){
    var atId = this.id;
    // do something with it
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is loop through the direct-descendant divs of the `#test` div; you would do this using the `>` descendant selector, and the jQuery `.each()` iterator. You can also use the jQuery `.css()` and `.attr()` methods for styling and retrieving the id respectively.

```
$("#test > div").each(function(index){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).css(/* apply styles */);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery.

This code can be addapted to your needs:

```
$testDiv = ​$('div#test')​​​​​​​​​​​​.first();    
$('div', $testDiv).css("margin", '50px');​​​​
```